# Largest value in Visual Studio C or C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition there is the following file:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\SDK\include\shared\intsafe.h"

It has the following value for maximum value for a 16-byte integer:

`#define UINT128_MAX     0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffui128`

I also found the following code in the limits file

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\VC\include\limits.h"

```
#if _INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS >= 128
    // minimum signed 128 bit value
    #define _I128_MIN   (-170141183460469231731687303715884105727i128 - 1)
    // maximum signed 128 bit value
    #define _I128_MAX     170141183460469231731687303715884105727i128
    // maximum unsigned 128 bit value
    #define _UI128_MAX    0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffui128
#endif
```

This is grayed out as if `_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS >= 128` is not defined.

And I can't find a data type for a 128-bit integer anywhere.  Can MS C or C++ handle a value that large or not?  I have a new PC that should have the capability to handle math for integers that large.  TIA.

Comment: C and C++ don't have any upper limit for the types. Implementations will define their own limits. However, unlike gcc, there's no 128-bit integer type in MSVC even though there are a few "hints" in it (probably some remnants of prior experients or something for the future) [Can I use 128-bit integer in MSVC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23775248/995714), [How to enable __int128 on Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6759592/995714)

Comment: Note that C allows for extended integer types that may be 128 bit _without_ supporting 128-bit constants.

Comment: Thx for your on-going support, chux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't data types for 128-bit integers that work like the ones for 64-bit sizes and below. If you want them, you'll have to implement them yourself. Using GMP or boost::multiprecision is always an option.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply.  That's unfortunate.

Comment: There are plenty of libraries available.

Comment: I would normally like to use the normal quick math of 64-bit integers, unless the numbers are too large.  I'm not exactly sure how to know when it's necessary to switch to multiprecision math.  Maybe by checking the number of digits?

Comment: if you don't need arbitrary precision, switch to gcc or Clang and use [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html), or use a 128-bit fixed-width type [C++ 128/256-bit fixed size integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5242819/995714), [Representing 128-bit numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1188939/995714), [Fastest 128 bit integer library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3692602/995714)

Comment: Thx for the tips, @phuclv.